# Can I implement a "reveal" feature at the token level, not the collection level?

Tags: solidity, ethereum-wallet-dapp, dapp-development, solidity-0.8.x

In my limited experience, solidity contracts are implemented with a `reveal` function that will allow the artwork of an NFT to remain hidden until the contract owner invokes the `reveal` command.  In the meantime, a `hidden image / path` is used.

This is all configured in the contract and can be manipulated on etherscan or with a dapp.

> **Question**
>
> Can we implement a `reveal[NFT]` capability per token?  (internal: I guess we could keep an array on `is_revealed`
> boolean values per token...)  Is that possible?

> **Use Case**
>
> I want my contract to mint tokens gradually over time
> and I do not want to reveal all at once, I want a single reveal per
> token -- like fortune cookie, preferably user invoked (in a dapp).

Comment: I figure out how to do this BTW.  will share the results - whoever is interested.

Comment: Please add them as an answer so other know when they look at the question that the answer is there

Comment: Sorry for not following up here.  The fix was this: every ERC721 contract (NFT) has metadata and a resource (image/video/cryptovoxel whatever/etc).  The key is that your resource url can point to an API as opposed to a static resource. that is as long as you can guarantee that api will be online 24/7 for the useful lifetime of your NFT collection. 

so point to an API, not an image. then return whatever you'd like.  there is precedence for a dynamic NFT.  rendering differently from different locations perhaps.